# Allowing translation later on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, localization, external

I have an application that has two localization options at the moment through .resx files. I would like to allow other users to translate the website into their own languages as they desire.

1) Is there a way to do so? 
2) Or do they have to create a .resx file through some kind of a .resx creator and send it to me so than I can add it to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asp.net compiles on the fly your web site, you can attach new resx later.

I like [Resex](http://resex.codeplex.com/) as resx file editor because it allows to categorize the resources and help to find not translated strings.